# cannot drag query across multiple rows (overwrites data)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

Is it possible to click and drag queries?

I describe my problem below and also have a [reference sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lPeI2RvfyOzlsF5eGaBrRoeNKREzuUr-Wp9NzrIQCiY/edit?usp=sharing).

cells A1:B5

| Category | Withdrawal |
| --- | --- |
| CatA | 4 |
| CatB | 2 |
| CatA | 6 |
| CatB | 11 |

---

cells C1:C3

| Check For |
| --- |
| CatA |
| CatB |

---

I want to put the following query into cell D1 and drag it down to D2: `=query(A2:B5,"select sum(B) where A = '"&C2&"'",0)`, but I get the following error: `Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in D2.`

How can I extend the query so each subsequent looks at the next 'Check For' cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
=query(A2:B5,"select sum(B) where A = '"&C2&"'",0)
```

use

```
=query($A$2:$B$5,"select sum(B) where A = '"&C2&"' label sum(B) ''",0)
```

- `label sum(B) ''` prevents that `sum(B)` be added as a column header, so now the formula will return a single value which will allow you to drag down your the formula.
- `$A$2:$B$5` will prevent that the reference be changed will dragging the formula.

NOTE:

When copying formulas by *dragging* or *copy & pasting* cells / ranges it's important to know how references work in Google Sheets.

- `A1` is a *relative reference*. This type of reference will change as the formula is dragged. If you drag it down, `A1` will be automatically changed to `A2`, `A3`, and so on. If you drag it right, `A1` will be automatically changed to `B1`, `C1`, and so on.
- `$A$1` is an *absolute reference*. This type of reference will be kept the same.
- It's possible to have one of the dimensions as absolute while the other as relative i.e. on `$A1` the column dimension is absolute while the row dimension is relative.

Related

- [In Google Spreadsheets how to make a relative column reference within a query?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/140891/88163)

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
=query($A$2:$B,"select sum(B) where A = '"&C2&"' label sum(B) '' ",0)
```

and drag it down for as many rows as needed.
Please notice how we also need to **lock the range `$A$2:$B`**. We would otherwise may get strange results.

As an alternative use a single

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(C2:C),SUMIF($A$2:$A,"="&C2:C,$B$2:$B),""))
```

[image]

Comment: I see you have accepted the answer by Ruben. **Be very careful**. The formula may lead to wrong results.  **You need to lock the ranges**. See [what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPDA0.png) if you don't.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: **A warning to the OP and future users.** That was my comment. Still. It is amazing -though not quite ethical (especially coming from a lately elected moderator)- how your following actions of editing your answer [again](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/153831/2) and [again](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/153831/3) and [again](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/153831/4) are structured towards primarily serving yourself than the users. Glad I could help :)

Comment: There are no ethical issues on improving a post on the contrary it's encouraged to do so.